# link on react not redirecting

Tags: reactjs, redirect, hyperlink

I'm using Link on react-router-dom and whenever I see my terminal it always says " 'Link' is defined but not used" but I already declared in on my code and my Link tag does not redirect on on a component it stays on the page and never refreshes it but the url changes

here's my block code on my div to Link:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import user from '../images/user.png';


const ContactCard = (props) =>{
const {id, name, email} = props.contact;
return(

    <div className="item">
    
        <img className="ui avatar image" src={user} alt="user"/>
    <div className="content">
        <Link to={`/contact/${id}`}>
        <div className="header"> {name}</div>
        <div>{email} </div>
        </Link>
        </div>

        

        <i className="trash alternate outline icon right floated"  
        style={{color:"red"}}
        onClick={()=> props.clickHandler(id)}>
    
        </i>
        
        
    </div>
  
 );

};


export default ContactCard;
```

the error i'm getting:

Line 2:10:  'Link' is defined but never used

Comment: Your code is fine. Please check again to make sure you have <Link in the component

Comment: i have the route tag on my app.js
     <Route path="/contact/ :id" component={ContactDetail} />

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling react router and start the app over. Also, remove `React.StrictMode` - it prevents it from redirecting. It actually does but you have to refresh your page to see it.